# Inverse Transform ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes

Tags: python, numpy

request help - keep getting ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes while executing inverse_transform (the last line in the code below). Any pointers greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

## Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

training_set = pd.read_csv('daily.csv')

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder

onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
training_set = onehotencoder.fit_transform(training_set).toarray()

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

sc = MinMaxScaler()
training_set = sc.fit_transform(training_set)
X_train = training_set[:, 0:15]
y_train = training_set[:, 15:]
dims = len(X_train[0])
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (len(X_train), 1, dims))

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM

regressor = Sequential()
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 4, activation = 'sigmoid', input_shape = (None, dims)))
regressor.add(Dense(units = 4))
regressor.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 32, epochs = 50)

test_set = pd.read_csv('daily_test.csv')

onehotencoder2 = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
test_set = onehotencoder2.fit_transform(test_set).toarray()

inputs = sc.transform(test_set)
inputs = inputs[:, 0:15]
inputs = np.reshape(inputs, (len(inputs), 1, dims))

predicted = regressor.predict(inputs)
predicted = sc.inverse_transform(predicted)
```

Comment: It seems that reshaping was the problem. So worked around that as follows:  test_seto = test_set[:, 0:15]
test_set = test_seto
test_set = np.reshape(test_set, (len(test_set), 1, dims))
predicted = regressor.predict(test_set)
test_set2 = np.concatenate((test_seto, predicted), axis=1)
test_set2 = sc.inverse_transform(test_set2)

Answer (score 0):

Tough this would sound weird, it did help me fix the error.

If in case you are using "excel" to tamper "csv training data" file and if you are deleting a column from the excel,

you would end up with a blank ",," value in your csv data which would cause the issue for me.